# Install Cloudwatch agent on EC2 in a private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-vpc

I am trying to install the cloud watch agent on an EC2 instance behind a private subnet (no internet access). All the documentation online seems to get the RPM using the internet (either through S3 download links or AWS System manager). What I am trying to figure out is how to get the RPM without the internet. I have a VPCE setup for s3 which is able to get objects from my own bucket, however, as per my understanding, it doesn't work with download links.
Documentation I am trying to follow:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/download-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html

If it matters I am using terraform to deploy my infra.

Is there a solution for this?

UPDATE:
Shell script for EC2 instance launch

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user
aws s3 cp s3://${bucket_name}/${zip_file} ${zip_file} --region ${region}

wget https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent-us-east-1/amazon_linux/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
```

VPC route table:

> 101.0.0.0/16  local   active  No
>
> pl-xxxxx (com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3, 54.231.0.0/17, 52.216.0.0/15, 3.5.16.0/21, 3.5.0.0/20)  vpce-xxxxxxx    active.  No

Comment: Can you clarify more. The route table you posted is incorrect. There is no such address like `101.0.0.0/16`. Also is it main table? Do your subnets with the instances in question use the main table or they have custom route tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The S3 download link is already provided in the documentation for all the regions. Since you've already set up the S3 gateway VPC endpoint, if you use the region-specific S3 download link **of your region**, it will work like a charm. **You don't need NAT or anything else.**

Comment: That's what I figured but it's not working as I expected. I have a shell script that executes at instance launch (EC2).

It downloads the objects from my personal bucket but the s3 download link is not working. I have updated the question to show both shell script and the VPC route table

Comment: @user2977535 Can you do a `dig +short s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` in your EC2 instance?

Comment: Not unless I have a route to an Internet Gateway

Comment: @user2977535 Could you also check the route table is associated with the private subnet that your EC2 instances are in?

Comment: @user2977535 Could you also check the [enableDnsSupport](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-support) in the VPC is on?

Comment: Yep double-checked the routing table. I tried creating ec2 under public subnet without a 0.0.0.0 route, even that doesn't work. DNS support doesn't help either

Comment: @user2977535 It looks like a DNS issue. Can you try this? `dig @169.254.169.253 +short s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: It was actually working, it seems my shell script had some weird character and it silently kept failing. Accepting this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

To access internet from private subnet, you generally need:

1. [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) or [NAT instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) in a public subnet(s)
2. Modified **route tables** of the private subnet(s) to point internet traffic (0.0.0.0/0) to the NAT devices.

The alternative is to store CloudWatch Agent in **S3** and download it from there via **S3 VPC Gateway**. If this does not work, have to verify your VPC Endpoint settings and route tables.

Also you can prepare a **golden AMI image** in the public subnet with the agent and any other software which requires internet to be installed. Then you deploy your instances in the private subnet from the AMI.